# Cannot reset/change tab order

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tab-ordering

I have a form and I am trying to set the focus to Shipment# text box without having to programmatically do it.

[image]

I am using View->Tab Order but I am not able to set the right-panel of the split container to 0. Visual studio is allowing to only set to 0 the left panel of the splitcontainer.

[image]

I tried though the properties to set tab order to 0 for the Shipment# text box and change it to a higher number for all the Print, Compare.. buttons but still Shipment# doesn't get the focus.

Why can't I set the Tab order to 0 for Shipment# text box using View->Tab Order?

Comment: I +1 because you use `comic sans ms`.

Comment: No I am not. It is a picture.

Comment: Probably there are some hidden (or behind) panels here that mess with the taborder settings.

Comment: Why not use `textboxShipment.Focus()`?

Comment: If you're using the designer (and not the properties window part) you probably have to click on the split panel itself, not one of its children. You might need to temporarily undock one of the children so you can actually click on it

Comment: @René Vogt, I could do it but I would like to understand where I am wrong and learn from it. I believe there is an explanation why it is not possible and maybe another solution except setting the focus

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Express.  Try editing the XAML code by putting 'TabIndex="#"' where the '#' is the number of the index you want.

A Quick example:

```
MainWindow.xaml
....
TextBox x:Name="SomeTextBox" TabIndex="0"
TextBox x:Name="AnotherTextBox" TabIndex="1"
```

Would put these text boxes in order from 0 to 1 and so on.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can set the TabIndex property of SplitContainer Panels via the Properties window, you have to do it via code

```
splitContainer1.Panel1.TabIndex = 1;
splitContainer1.Panel2.TabIndex = 0;
```

Would give the right(or bottom) Panel focus first, and then the control with lowest TabIndex on that Panel should get focus.

You could also use

```
SplitContainer.ActiveControl = controlName;
```

Either way, I think you'll have to do it in code.

Comment: Thanks but Tabindex is not property of splitContainer1.Panel1. No possibility to do it via code as you mentioned

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitterpanel.tabindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

For the record, that BrowsableAttribute tag is the reason you don't see the property in the properties window, I believe.